# Lifetime on trait returning iterator

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm working with a trait requiring a function returning an iterator without consuming the object. The iterator itself returns copies of data values, not references. As the iterator implementation requires a reference to the object it is iterating over, I end up having to declare lots of lifetimes (more than I would have thought necessary, but could not get it to compile otherwise). I then run into trouble with borrow duration - a minimal "working" example is as follows:

```
pub trait MyTrait<'a> {
    type IteratorType: Iterator<Item=u32>;
    fn iter(&'a self) -> Self::IteratorType;
    fn touch(&'a mut self, value: u32);
}
struct MyStruct {
    data: Vec<u32>
}
struct MyIterator<'a> {
    structref: &'a MyStruct,
    next: usize,
}
impl<'a> Iterator for MyIterator<'a> {
    type Item = u32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        if self.next < self.structref.data.len() {
            self.next += 1;
            return Some(self.structref.data[self.next-1]);
        } else {
            return None;
        }
    }
}
impl<'a> MyTrait<'a> for MyStruct {
    type IteratorType = MyIterator<'a>;
    fn iter(&'a self) -> Self::IteratorType {
        return MyIterator { structref: &self, next: 0 };
    }
    fn touch(&'a mut self, value: u32) {
    }
}
fn touch_all<'a,T>(obj: &'a mut T) where T: MyTrait<'a> {
    let data: Vec<u32> = obj.iter().collect();
    for value in data {
        obj.touch(value);
    }
}
```

Compiling this gives me the error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*obj` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
|
39 |     let data: Vec<u32> = obj.iter().collect();
|                          --- immutable borrow occurs here
40 |     for value in data {
41 |         obj.touch(value);
|         ^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
42 |     }
43 | }
| - immutable borrow ends here
```

By my limited understanding of lifetimes, I would have thought the immutable borrow only extends to the line where I make it - after all the iterator is consumed and I no longer hold any references to obj or data contained in it. Why does the lifetime of the borrow extend to the entire function, and how do I fix this?

Here is a sequence of steps on how I arrived here - running the code should provide the associated compiler errors.

- [no explicit lifetimes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=435bdbbdbf8d848491554b77d6585ee4&version=stable&backtrace=0)
- [IteratorType needs lifetime](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e37a4cf6a79ae336a585e8ed44320272&version=stable&backtrace=0)
- [Unconstrained lifetime parameter](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=14919832cc7c634bb169bbafd48ea990&version=stable&backtrace=0)

To clarify: I'd like to be able to make calls like this:

```
fn main() {
    let obj: MyStruct = MyStruct { data : vec![] };
    touch_all(&mut obj);
}
```

rather than having to call

```
    touch_all(&mut &obj);
```

which would be needed for the proposal by mcarton (1st and 2nd comment).

Comment: `impl<'a> MyTrait for &'a MyStruct` makes more sense

Comment: See https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1dbba3c2cd3fe1aec9339aeeb0408a29&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: Thanks, that looks much better. However I don't quite understand why this works - it looks to me like you are saying that the trait is implemented by a reference to MyStruct, not by MyStruct itself? Is that some form of rust auto-dereferencing in action?

Comment: Actually, this will cause code like this: `let obj: MyStruct = MyStruct { data : vec![] }; touch_all(&mut obj);` to fail, as MyStruct does not implement the trait. So I'd have to write `touch_all(&mut &obj)` which feels more than strange.

Comment: To clarify, `fn iter(&'a self)` in your original code, will borrow the containing type as long as it lives. That is why the borrow extends to the entire function. (You would also not been able to call `touch` twice - not even in the for-loop).

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm starting to understand - in touch_all, obj is borrowed for the duration of 'a, and since obj is used throughout 'a must be the entire duration of touch_all. The same timeline 'a is used as parameter to MyTrait, meaning iter() will borrow for the same duration, even though it wouldn't need to. So I'd need to separate the lifetime of obj from the lifetime of the trait (as is the case for your implementation). Actually tried that before but ran into other errors, but at least it's clearer to me now.